# Can I add extra transform to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

So, if a div already has a transfrom, can I add to the existing rotate?
Something like this:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red; transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(10deg)" id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.transformRotateX += 10deg;
})
</script>
```

Comment: not using the same `id`. An `id` can only be used once on the page

Comment: there's only one element and one id

Comment: yes. if i don't need jquery solutions i don't write that tag there

Comment: ah i thought you meant can you reuse the script for other divs

Comment: sorry for my english :/

Comment: nah it wasnt the english i just understood wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is rely on [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/), which allows you to modify individual transform properties cumulatively. The advantage is that velocity.js relies on JavaScript, not jQuery, for animations, making it more efficient and prevents layout thrashing.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("myDiv");

// Establish initial transformation onload
Velocity(
  ele,
  {
    rotateX: '90deg',
    rotateY: '10deg'
  },
  {
    duration: 0
  });

// Progressively manipulate rotateX property upon each click
document.addEventListener("click",function(){
  Velocity(
    ele,
    {
      translateZ: 0, // Force HA by animating a 3D property
      rotateX: "+=10deg"
    },
    {
      duration: 0
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;" id="myDiv"></div>
```

---

Of course, if you want to rely on jQuery and/or Zepto for their ease of element selection, that is also possible:

```js
$(function() {
  // Establish initial transformation onload
  $('#myDiv').velocity({
    rotateX: '90deg',
    rotateY: '10deg'
  }, {
    duration: 0;
  });
  
  // Progressively manipulate rotateX property upon each click
  $('#myDiv').click(function() {
    $(this).velocity({
      rotateX: '+=10deg'
    }, {
      duration: 0
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;" id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: HA for "hardware acceleration". Triggering 3D transformations, even with a value of 0, will cause the browser rendering engine to offload the painting to GPU.

Comment: Can i do with a full class?

Comment: What do you mean by "full class"?